# One shot inference with Variational Autoencoders using proposal mean

Tags: neural-networks, unsupervised-learning, variational-bayes, density-estimation, generative-models

Let's say you have an already trained Variational Autoencoder where the parameters are $\phi, \theta$ for the recognition and generative models respectively. Let's also assume you have the following Gaussian factorization scheme:
$
\newcommand{\Norm}{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand{\pz}{p(z)}
\newcommand{\ptheta}{p_{\theta}}
\newcommand{\encoding}{q_{\phi}(z \g x)}
\newcommand{\decoding}{p_{\theta}(x \g z)}
\newcommand{\g}{\,|\,}
\newcommand{\qphi}{q_{\phi}}
\newcommand{\qphizgivenx}[2]{\qphi(#1 \g #2)}
$
$$
\begin{split}
\pz &= \Norm(0,I)\\
\decoding &= \Norm(\mu_{\theta}(z),\sigma^2I) \\
\encoding &=\Norm(\mu_{\phi}(x),diag(\sigma^2_{\phi}(x)))
\end{split}
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^d,z \in \mathbb{R}^r, d>>r$, and $\mu_\phi, \sigma^2_\phi$ functions are neural network encoders while $\mu_{\theta}$ is a neural network decoder.

Now, according to [Kingma & Welling 2019 p. 30](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.02691.pdf) $\log \ptheta(x)$ can be approximated by an importance sampling procedure with $L$ iterations:
$$
\log \ptheta(x) \approx \log \frac{1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^{L}\frac{\ptheta(x,z^{(l)})}{\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}}    
$$

Here, $z^{(l)}$ are sampled from $\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}$. This operation is too costly for me so I want to do this in one shot so $L=1$. My question is, can I justify that one single sample should be the mean of the proposal distribution, thus $z^{(1)} = \mu_\phi(x)$?